# Unable to access downloaded files in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-download-manager

So I download .mp3 songs from provided URLs using the following code:

```
private long DownloadData (Uri uri) {

    long downloadReference;

    // Create request for android download manager
    downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setTitle("Data Download");
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | 
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(DownloadSongActivity.this, 
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ,"doesn'twork.mp3");

    downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    return downloadReference;
}
```

I then attempt to give user access to these files in the app using the following code to get them

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());
    File[] downloadedFiles = path.listFiles();


    if(downloadedFiles == null){
        System.out.println("DownloadedFiles are null");
    } else if(downloadedFiles.length == 0){
        System.out.println("DownloadedFiles are empty");
    } else{
        System.out.println("DownloadedFiles are not empty");
    }
```

However it seems that downloadedFiles always is null. Any suggestions.
Here are some pictures for reference to

If I go to Files -> Downloads

[Image Reference link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7oop.png)

Comment: have you given write_external_storage permission in your manifest file?     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: @userI without  `write_external_storage` permission hewouldn't be able to download files.

Comment: yes. Some of the permission given are:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: setMimeType to mp3 and it will work

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit just did request.setMimeType(".mp3");  same problem

Comment: try setting "audio/mpeg3" instead of .mp3

Comment: I think you need to give runtime permissions if you running app on android version>=23. If you have added `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in manifest, then in your mobile  goto `settings>application>your app>permission> switch on storage permission`. and try again.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit did that, still same problem. I think it more that im accessing a different directory than where the songs have been stored as File[] downloadedFiles is null, but I don't know why

Comment: @hricardo follow my last comment once.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan yes thank you, now the downloaded files are just empty instead of null

Comment: that means you don't have any files in that directory,am I right?

Comment: @MohammedFarhan technically yes, but as you have seen in the picture in my post, i do have files in my directory

Comment: @MohammedFarhan removing the absolutePath() does not work. Im just wondering if I am accessing a different directory than the one stored the songs in

Answer (score 0):

[Try this, it is definitely working](http://www.google.com)